# How to prevent Google Chrome from deleting session cookies after the browser window is closed?

Tags: google-chrome

Some websites (e.g. Amazon) add a session cookie once you login, that expires once the browser window is closed. I'd like to prevent the default behavior and force Chrome to keep those cookies forever.

Is there a browser setting or plugin that would allow me to do so? Note that you can achieve this by using the "Continue where you left off" setting, but I'd rather not use it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Chrome extension which uses the [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) API, and [chrome.cookies.remove](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-remove) the session cookie, and immediately [chrome.cookies.set](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-set) it again with an explicit expiration time.